# C# regular expression excluding tags with random element names

Tags: c#, expression, inverse

I'm trying to get the opposite of this expression and it's giving me some trouble.

Ex.

```
expression: (?<={{)(.*?)(?=}})
string: this is a question with a textbox {{textbox}} ok
results: textbox
```

Looking for something like

```
expression: !(?<={{)(.*?)(?=}})
string:this is a question with a textbox {{textbox}} ok 
results: this is a question with a textbox ok
```

Also, I should note that whats in the {{}}'s is not always textbox and will be random alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about performing a replacement?

```
string replaced = yourRegex.Replace(original, string.Empty);
```

`replaced` would be your “match”. And you wouldn’t need the assertions anymore, either.